# How to throw validation error from a feed hook in gravity forms?

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

For example some error occurred in one of the feed processing. How will I trigger an error that will appear as a validation error to the user?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the [gform_validation](https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_validation/) filter, fetch the feed (from your add-on) that will be used to process the submission using the `GFFeedAddon::get_single_submission_feed()` method, and the run your validation logic.